# how to split input data variable into small group of inputs in shell

Tags: bash, shell

I have a list of devices and would like to execute the same commands across all of them. But my script is taking much time as the input file is pretty big. So i would like to divide the input list into small sub files and wanted to run the jobs in parallel for all devices so that execution will happen quickly. Could you suggest how can i accomplish this.

Comment: you can use the command "split" to split the file in many files as you like

Comment: `man split` and `man parallel`

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where you are stuck. Are you able to show us how you are currently processing the files sequentially and do you have practical limits e.g. on how many CPUs you can use before the drawbacks of parallelization outweigh the benefits?

Answer (score -2):

Use `parallel` and limit the number of jobs running in parallel using the `-j` option.

Comment: This may start a LOT of background tasks, which in the worst case would grind the system to an unresponsive halt.